# fancybox changing image orientation

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have an image that I'm using as I test fancybox capabilities. The image is portrait/vertically oriented. The sizes of the image are 375x500, 450x600, 600x800, and 3000x4000. They all display properly in the portrait orientation except for the 3000x4000 - it's size is reduced for displaying on the screen but  gets flipped to landscape orientation. How do I stop that behavior or is this a bug? I've tried with fancybox 1.3.4 and 2

This works :

```
 <a href="_images/fancybox/seagulls20121230-07-600x800p.jpg" rel="gallery" title="CEB's pic 600x800"> <img src="_images/fancybox/seagulls20121230-07-600x800p-thmb.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="Honda Pilot 600x800" /> </a>
```

This doesn't work - same image, just bigger

```
<a href="_images/fancybox/seagulls20121230-07-4000x3000p.jpg" rel="gallery" title="CEB's pic 3000x4000"> <img src="_images/fancybox/seagulls20121230-07-4000x3000p-thmb.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="Honda Pilot 3000x4000" /> </a>
```

the fancybox code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery a').fancybox({
        overlayColor: '#060',
        overlayOpacity: .3,
        transitionIn: 'elastic',
        transitionOut: 'elastic',
        easingIn: 'easeInSine',
        easingOut: 'easeOutSine',
        titlePosition: 'outside',
        cyclic: true
    });
}); // end ready
```

Comment: and the code you use?

Comment: Here is a big image (3456x4608) opening fine using fancybox 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/5YTdW/2/

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code there, not in the comments area ;)

Comment: JFK thanks for editing my question and the advice where to put the code - I'm a newbee to stackoverflow

Comment: JFK wrote: "Here is a big image (3456x4608) opening fine using fancybox 2" ... so I created my same image the size you used (3456x4606 - a 3x4 aspect ratio which is LARGER than the one I'm having trouble with) and that WORKED! Still the only one that doesn't work is the 3000x4000. Have you tried it with those exact proportions? (hmmm, puzzeling) Thanks for your help

Comment: The flipped orientation happens on my home testing server (Apache) so I decided to upload it to the web where I do remote testing (http://bradbury-test2.com/complete_fancybox.html) There it doesn't flip, it says "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." (but shows correct title). You can access my remote testing site to see all the source code for that page if you like.

Comment: in a server environment, there is a big difference between `image.jpg` and `image.JPG` (names and extensions are case sensitive) ... AND your image is displayed as rotated because it is like that!!! I downloaded it and its format is as displayed in fancybox. So make sure you uploaded the right oriented image to your server .... this is not a fancybox issue.

Comment: JFK - you have been very helpful. Thank You. I was viewing the image in Photoshop, Picasa and directly with the Chrome Browser - they all displayed it as portrait orientation. However when using Microsoft Products it showed it as landscape - just as you said. Obviously, one must be careful of what product they use to view the image (lesson learned). Another lesson is that I used that image as the source for exporting smaller versions out of Photshop. When exporting, Photoshop must correct/change the orientation to coincide with the EXIF data. (another lesson learned). Again, thanks